# Is there an API implemented to invite an array of friends to a Facebook Group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I've been working for about an hour trying to figure out how to invite friends via API methods, however I don't see any documentation.  Is there a current method I'm just not finding?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is currently no Groups API that can do this

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a POST request to

https://graph.facebook.com/GROUP_ID/members?userids=USER_ID1,USER_ID2&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

The manage_groups permission must be granted for this request to work